# R: Removing Duplicates Within a Row of a Data Frame

Tags: r, unique

I am working with some data in R where I have generated columns of category data based on comments within the data frame.

The comments are spread over multiple columns for each row, and so each comment needed to be categorized.  The result for the category columns looks something like this:

```
Category1  Category2             Category3             Category4
No change  Presentation Changed  Presentation Changed  No change
No change  No change             Scroll Changed
```

Within these rows, I need to only keep the unique values (remove the duplicates).  I do not want to remove entire rows or entire columns, just convert the duplicates in the row to blanks.  So the new example would look as such:

```
Category1  Category2             Category3             Category4
No change  Presentation Changed  
No change                        Scroll Changed
```

Let me know if there are any other details about the code or table that are necessary for solving this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `tidyverse` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <-
  tibble(
    Category1 = c('No change', 'No change'),
    Category2 = c('Presentation Changed', 'No change'),
    Category3 = c('Presentation Changed', 'Scroll Changed'),
    Category4 = c('No change', '')
  ) 

data %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(Category, Value, -id) %>%
  group_by(id, Value) %>%
  mutate(cnt = n()) %>%
  group_by(id, Value) %>%
  mutate(dup = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Value = if_else(cnt > 1 & dup > 1, '', Value)) %>%
  select(id, Category, Value) %>%
  spread(Category, Value)
```